# Angular 2 Reactive Forms: Cannot find control with path

Tags: angular, typescript, web, frontend, angular-reactive-forms

I try to dynamically add Roles to my User/Roles-application. I have a Formarray where i can show the Roles of the User in the Edit View. And there is a button for adding more Roles to the User. But when i press the button "Add Role", i got this error message:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'rolesArr -> 1 -> name'

In this example, i try to add more than one Role to a User that i want to create.

Here is my Code:

**users-edit.component.html** (excerpt)

```
<div formArrayName="rolesArr" >
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
        <button class="btn btn-default"
                type="button"
                (click)="addRole()">Add Role
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div *ngFor="let role of roles.controls; let i=index">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" [attr.for]="i">Role</label>

            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input class="form-control"
                        [id]="i" 
                        type="text" 
                        placeholder="Role" 
                        formControlName="name" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**users-edit.component.ts** (excerpt)

```
addRole() {
    this.roles.push(this.fb.group(new Roles()));
}

ngOnInit(): void {

    this.userForm = this.fb.group({
        username: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
        firstname: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
        lastname: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
        password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)]],
        rolesArr: this.fb.array([])
    });

    this.sub = this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(
        params => {
            let id = +params['id']; //converts string'id' to a number
            this.getUser(id);
        }
    );
}
getUser(id: number) {
        this.userService.getUser(id).subscribe(
                user => this.onUserRetrieved(user)
            );
}
onUserRetrieved(user: User): void {
    console.log("OnUserRetrieved: " + user.firstname);
    if (this.userForm) {
        this.userForm.reset();
    }
    this.users = user;

    if (this.users.id === 0) {
        this.pageTitle = 'Add User';
    } else {
        this.pageTitle = `Edit User: ${this.users.username}`;
    }

    //Update the data on the form
    this.userForm.patchValue({
        username: this.users.username,
        firstname: this.users.firstname,
        lastname: this.users.lastname,
        password: this.users.password
    });

    const roleFGs = this.users.roles.map(roles => this.fb.group(roles));
    const roleFormArray = this.fb.array(roleFGs);
    this.userForm.setControl('rolesArr', roleFormArray);
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a form group with the controls for `Roles` as below,

```
createRole() :  FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
            name: '',
            type: '',

    });
}
```

Then you should push the role as below,

```
addRole() {
    this.roles.push(this.createRole());
}
```

Comment: thank you man! i knew it was so easy. but didnt know what the problem is. it works perfect now

Comment: happy to help you. anything else you need?

Comment: now i really could use your help. If you don't mind, can you please have a look on my issue posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330393/how-to-realize-oauth2-authentication-in-angular) ?

Answer (score 1):

While Aravind's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44220367/6754146) works you are still able to do the exact same thing you are doing now:

```
addRole() {
    this.roles.push(this.fb.group(new Roles()));
}
```

but the control requires default values for your properties in the class (which is exactly what Aravind's solution does, it creates an object with default values)

so if your current `Roles` class looks something like this:

```
export class Roles {
    public name: string;
    public type: string;
}
```

you should add default values like this:

```
export class Roles {
    public name: string = '';
    public type: string = '';
}
```

This allows angular to find your properties as control's

Additional information:
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#use-formarray-to-present-an-array-of-formgroups

Comment: You are a legend! After hours of searching and refactoring **this** is what has finally fixed my "Cannot find control with path" error! Thank you!